# How to stop the url in iframe from opening the print tab

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a webpage by combining the the multiple urls in a single page using iframe. I am able to get the individual pages to the single page, but the individual pages open the print tab how to stop them from doing so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="individual_page1" width="100%"></iframe><!--This src creates its own print tab-->
    <iframe src="individual_page2" width="100%"></iframe><!--This src creates its own print tab-->
    <iframe src="individual_page3" width="100%"></iframe><!--This src creates its own print tab-->
</body>
</html>
```

1. Used sandbox attribute but it hinders the individual page contents.
2. target="_self" also did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a fourth iframe, give it a name and use it as the target for the print action. use this as an inspiration: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

If you are using window.print() to open the print tab, maybe 'allow-modals' is what you are looking for? it will allow your iframes to open the print dialog as a modal.

Comment: Sorry, if I could not explain my point, the issue is that these links open the print tab. If there are 3 iframes these will open their own print tab, and I will have to close them individually before I am able to view the main page, I want to stop these links from opening the print tab.

Comment: can you show me the links that open the print tab? @imperious27

Comment: I cannot share the links, but these links are generated when the print button is clicked over a multipage form merging the response of multiple pages into a single page which opens in the print tab. So, I am trying to capture the response from numerous single-page-generated forms using iframe to a single page.

Comment: @imperious27 We can't fix secret code. I doubt it's the link itself opening a print tab, rather there's some JavaScript executed when such a link is activated.

Comment: @Teemu can we still stop it using iframe from doing so?

Comment: @imperious27 If it's a third-party page in the iframe(s), there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @Teemu is there a way to fetch data from that page to my main page without iframes

Comment: @imperious27 Not in the context of the tags you've assigned to the question, you'd need server-side code for that task. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy